# How to create gradient button for mobile using Delphi XE7?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, firemonkey-style

I'm using Delphi XE7 for creating Android / iOS mobile application And how can I create the gradient button ([Sample Gradient button](http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/201303/page07.html))using FireMonkey Mobile application. Or should I need to use Style Book for applying the Gradient Colour in the Buttons?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the tutorial you posted. With Firemonkey everything (visually) is composed of primitive shapes and animations, so using the skills learned in that post, you could create your buttons in gimp, then create a style with hover over and onbutton press animations. If you haven't taken a look at this page yet I would read through it,

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Customizing_FireMonkey_Applications_with_Styles