# How to change the colour of the stringgrid particular cell using Delphi XE7

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, tgrid, firemonkey-style

I'm using Delphi XE7 for developing Android application. In that I have used **TStringGrid**  component and then I have used 
 `StringGrid.cells[0, 0] := 'Test'`
And how can I change the Font colour of that particular cell which I have shown in the code. And also I have [this sample code,](http://www.raize.com/Articles/FmxStringGridCellFonts.asp) but I can not change the font colour of the particular cell. Please anybody explain me how to change the font colour of the particular cell value. And I'm using Delphi XE7 and I'm targeting Android mobile.

Thanks..

Comment: What do you know about FMX styling? I suspect that you are not familiar with that. Until you become familiar with it you are likely to ask this question about every single control you ever use. It started with `TToolbar`, now `TStringGrid`.

Comment: You asked about TToolbar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28852006/62576) and gradient buttons [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28765103/62576), and now a stringgrid cell. Please do some research on working with FMX styles, so you're not asking how to do every little thing affecting appearance with every single control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I have found the solution which I required. Please follow the Steps. We can able to change the font color in TStringGrid itself, No need to use TGrid. Please follow the below steps.

First assign this in **FormCreate** event:

```
  StringGrid1.DefaultDrawing := False;
```

then write this in StringGrid **DrawColumnCell** event:

```
  Canvas.fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Green;
  Canvas.FillText(Bounds, (Value.AsString),
    false, 100, [], TTextAlign.taLeading, TTextAlign.taCenter);
```

Answer (score 1):

In a FireMonkey TStringGrid there are no per cell styling options. You will either need to use a third party grid control or roll something yourself from TGrid.

You can find plenty of material on the latter on my site at http://monkeystyler.com/guide

Answer (score 0):

Works in XE8 as well for the `TStringGrid` `OnDrawColumnCell` event.

Herewith an example that keeps the color on black but sets the font styling to bold. Tip, add 2 pixels padding for the font, from the left margin.

```
var Rect : TRectF;
begin
  Rect := Bounds;
  Rect.Left := Rect.Left + 2;
  Canvas.Font.Style := [TFontStyle.fsBold];
  Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Black;
  Canvas.FillText(Rect, (Value.AsString), false, 100, [], TTextAlign.taLeading, TTextAlign.taCenter);
end;
```

What I missed in the beginning was not setting the DefaultDrawing to false! After I set that, the event was accepting changes to the Canvas.